# JPA manytomany unidirectional mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have two classes: ExternalTask and ExternalSource.  ExternalTask has a List of ExternalSource and manytomany unidirectional relationship from ExternalTask to ExternalSource.

When I want to remove a ExternalSource I check to see if it is referenced by any ExternalTask.  If so, I check if this ExternalTask has only this externalsource in its List.  İf it is I remove ExternalTask completely; otherwise, I remove this externalsource from the list and merge externaltask.  Then I remove externalsource.  However, this is giving a constraint violation.  I tried using jointable with no cascade, cascadetype.update, and cascadetype.refresh, but it is still not working.  Any help?

This is the remove method:

```
public class Foo{
      public boolean deleteExternalDataStorage(Long sid) {
            EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
            try {
                et.begin();
                ExternalDataStorage s = em.find(ExternalDataStorage.class, sid);
                List<ExternalTask> tasks=(List<ExternalTask>) em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM ExternalTask t ").getResultList();
               for(ExternalTask t:tasks) {
                  if(t.getExternalSources().contains(s)){
                   t.getExternalSources().remove(s);
                   if(t.getExternalSources().isEmpty()){
                         em.remove(t);
                   }else{
                       em.merge(t);
                   }
                   }
               }


                em.remove(s);
                et.commit();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (et.isActive()) {
                    et.rollback();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


    }


    @Entity
    public class ExternalTask {

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "ExternalTask_ExternalSource", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EXID"))
        private  List<ExternalDataStorage> externalSources=new ArrayList<ExternalDataStorage>();


        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "ExternalTask_Archive", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AID"))
        protected  List<Archive> archives=new ArrayList<Archive>();


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "TID")
        protected Long id;


        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "name")
        protected String name;

        @Column(name = "description")
        protected String description;

        @Column(name="timeinterval" )
        protected String interval;



        @Column(name="startdate")
        @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        protected Date startDate;

        ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ExternalSource")
    public class ExternalDataStorage implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3926424342696569894L;        

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "EXID")
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "USERNAME")
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "PATH")
        private String path;


        @Column(name = "PORT")
        private int port = 22;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ISSECURE")
        private boolean isSecure=true;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ISINDEXINGENABLED")
        private boolean indexingEnabled;

        @Column(name = "INDEXINGREGEXP")
        private String indexingRegExp = "({time}\\d{8}-\\d{6})";

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "IP")
        private String ip;

        @Column
        private String password;

        @Column
        private String protocol;

        @Transient
        private String publicKey;

        @Column(name = "RSA_PRIV_KEY", length = 4096)
        private String privateKey;

        @Transient
        private String regExpTestStr="";

        @Transient
        private boolean testSucced;

        @Transient
        private InputAddress inputAddr;

        @Column
        private boolean authenticationType;

        @Column
        private boolean timeStampingEnable=true;

        @Column
        private String sshPath;

        @Column
        private  String filename="(.*\\.log)";

        public ExternalDataStorage() {
              inputAddr=new InputAddress();
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure violation is caused by `externalSource`, not, say, by `archives`?

Comment: constraint name null so iam not sure its source may be it is result from archive but why archives cause such a thing i dont think it is because of archives.

Comment: infact i dont one what happen join table when there exist no cascade.Any one know how hibernate handle join tables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you should have a bi-directional Many-to-Many relationship between your Task and Source. And clearly from your requirements, the Source should be the owning side in the relationship and donot use CascadeType=All when defining the relationship on the Source side, but use it on the Task side. If you do have the bi-directional relationship then you wouldn't have to check the entire lists of all the Tasks. That portion of the code is quadratic, it can be easily optimized using the b-directional mapping. Also if you make the Source the owning side without cascading options, the dependency is on the Source to attach/detach itself from the task. So all you would then need to do is:

```
if(source.getTaskList().size() == 1) {
    //remove the task source.getTaskList().get(0), this will remove the source also
}
else {
   //remove the source. The task is unaffected, as the source is the owning side
}
```